# JPivot implementation in Grails 3.0.1

Tags: grails, pivot, grails-plugin

Did anyone tried to implement JPivot in Grails? Can some one help me how I should import wcf and jp jars and dependencies and how to use their tag in my view?

Answer (score 1):

From what I know the jpivot project has been replaced by pivot4j (www.pivot4j.org)
There has been discussion on the mailing list how to use pivot4j and grails, you can read it at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/pivot4j-list/1st18J1G1_Q/UAuJeflMUpcJ

Comment: thanks for the reply. I've seen that post but could not get much info for Grails.